# What's the difference between "person who waits for..." and "person waiting for..."?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

Which one is right?

> Just an ordinary person **who waits** for an idiot.
>   Just an ordinary person **waiting** for an idiot.

I've been confused about this thing. I need someone help me to answer this or give me a correct sentence.

Comment: (1) Neither one is a complete sentence. (2) Either one could be fine inside a full sentence. (3) You might want to check out [ell.se].

Comment: Whether it's *who waits, waiting,* or *who is waiting*, your text isn't even a complete *sentence* (it's just a noun phrase). All variations are syntactically valid, though if you gave us a more complete context it might be that one should be preferred over another. But it would always be Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: I've voted to close as POB here on ELU, but on reflection it could be a valid question for ELL. ***Provided*** it's modified to make it clear that the specific aspect of syntax being queried is the difference between *Someone who **does** something* and *Someone who **is doing** something*.

Comment: Should i put the subject to make it clear?

Comment: @user The problem here is that both are grammatically correct, but which is best depends on the meaning you want to convey. Adding a subject and verb will resolve the issue that you have not given a complete sentence, but may do nothing to determine the intended meaning. That requires a lot more than a subject and a verb.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try to answer this question despite its vagueness.

First, both noun phrases are grammatical.

Second, a careless speaker or writer may use either without recognizing that they have different meanings.

Third, "person who waits for an idiot" would be appropriate to describe someone who habitually waits for an idiot. A "person waiting for an idiot" or a "person who is waiting for an idiot" would be appropriate to describe someone who merely happens to be waiting for an idiot at the current time. You may need to review the different usages of the simple present tense and the continuous present tense.

Fourth, no one can tell you which noun phrase is better to make your intended meaning clear unless you explain what you want convey.